Terraform "Failed to query available provider packages"
I have a Terraform module that consistently fails with an error message like this:
     Error: Failed to query available provider packages
    
    Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
    hashicorp/octopus: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a
    provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/octopus
    
    All modules should specify their required_providers so that external
    consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which
    modules are currently depending on hashicorp/octopus, run the following
    command:
        terraform providers

While I am using the Octopus Terraform provider, it is not available under hashicorp/octopus. The command terraform providers also does not show any usage of hashicorp/octopus.
What does this error mean?

This was just a typo in one of the resources in the module.
I had a resource like this:
resource octopus_tenant_project "my_tenant_project" {
   ...
}

The prefix of this resource was octopus. It should have been octopusdeploy i.e.:
resource octopusdeploy_tenant_project "my_tenant_project" {
   ...
}

The prefix was assumed to be hashicorp/octopus as described here, which does not exist, hence the error message.
